# How Do I Execute System Scripts from Within a Reactjs Project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a React project where I want to execute a server side bash script when a user clicks a button. This script would then run and return some output to be displayed back to the user. I know that NodeJS has a way to spawn or exec a particular command, but I'm not sure how I can take advantage of these features inside my React project.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is create a web service, that you will call with your React JS application. This web service will execute the script directly on the server and when it's done you can return data to display on your React JS application.

Comment: I think this is the way to go. Currently looking at making a restful API with node.js using express. React code would interact with the API and the node.js code could interact with the files on the server to get the results that I'm interested in.

Comment: Yes that's exactly it

Answer (score 3):

React runs in the browser, and with a purely remotely-served website there is no direct way to run a client-side bash script (that would be a major security issue). To run a bash script you need to run a native application on the client, which could then connect directly to your back end or be triggered via the [nativeMessaging API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging). Alternately you could use a framework like [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/) or [NW.js](https://nwjs.io/) to turn your React app into a native app, rather than running in the browser.

Comment: I would like to execute a server side script.